# Differential equation with delta dirac as the input

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dirac-delta

I have this formula:  $ C \frac{dv(t)}{d(t)} + Gv(t) = K \delta(t) $ 
and I have to calculate $v(0^{+})$ , given the $v(0^{-})$, without using the Laplace transformation. Could someone provide some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

For $t> 0$, it is easy to see that $v(t)=Ae^{-Gt/C}$.

where $A$ is a constant that will be found by enforcing the initial condition on $v(t)$.

Now, note that the presence of the Dirac Delta implies theta $v'(t)$ is discontinuous at $t=0$.  Formally, we can write

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}\left(Cv'(t)+Gv(t)\right)\,dt=K\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon} \delta(t)  \,dt \tag1
$$

The right-hand side of $(1)$ equals $K$.

Since $v$ is continuous, the contribution from integrating $v$ vanishes as $\epsilon \to 0$.

The left-hand side is then, $Cv(0^+)-Cv(0^-)=CA-Cv(0^-)$.  Now, simply solve for $A$.

Comment: Well, during our lesson, we had K =1 and our professor told that the solution was C*( v(0+) - v(0-) ) = 1... I am still having trouble following his  train of thought.

Comment: The integral of the bare Dirac delta (with no K in front and no transformation of the argument) over an interval which has zero in its interior is 1. Now compare that with the given answer...

Comment: @ian For any $\epsilon>0$, the functional $$\langle 1_{[-\epsilon,\epsilon]}, \delta \rangle=1$$where $\delta$ is the Dirac Delta distribution and $1$ is the indicator function.  So, I don't understand the comment.

Comment: @Dr.MV I should have pinged Alice1nw0, my apologies.

Comment: @Alice1nw0 My first comment here was directed at you.